# Select multiple rows with the same value, but one column not the same but is blank

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to do is get the records that have more than the same PartID but have a field that is blank and the other is not. SQL Server 2014.

```
SELECT COUNT(*), imbPartID 
FROM PartBins 
WHERE imbPartBinID = ''
GROUP BY imbPartID 
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Results:

```
imbPartID    imbPartLocation
----------------------------
11111        333-30
11111        320-12
22222
22222        243-43
33333        434-21
33333        122-09
44444
44444        651-04
```

etc...

So the results will show.

```
Column1      imbPartID
2            22222
2            44444
```

Comment: What's your dbms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want:

```
SELECT COUNT(*), imbPartID
FROM PartBins 
GROUP BY imbPartID
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN imbPartBinID = '' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0;
```